# When does Object.wait gets called

Tags: java, multithreading

When we have a thread that is executing a synchronized block and there is another thread that tries to access that synchronized block.

1. Will Object.wait be automatically called on the blocked thread?
2. Also, I see that in Object class, the definition of wait is :

   `public final native void wait(long timeout) throws InterruptedException;`

Does this mean that we have to manually write a function like the below in our class. I've seen many examples:

```
public void doWait(){
    synchronized(obj){
      while(!wasSignalled){
        try{
          obj.wait();
         } catch(InterruptedException e){...}
      }
      //clear signal and continue running.
      wasSignalled = false;
    }
  }

public void doNotify(){
    synchronized(obj){
      wasSignalled = true;
      obj.notify();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to ask.

Comment: I'm confused about the flow! When a thread A is trying to access a synchronized block which another thread B has already accessed, thread A goes to blocking state right? So, when does it go to wait? And I was asking if the thread A that is blocked automatically goes to waiting state?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `Object::wait` will not be called. The `wait`/`notify` mechanism is an additional layer on top of the basic locking provided by `synchronized`; it's possible to use `synchronized` without ever using `wait` or `notify`.

The basic `synchronized` mechanism is based around the idea of locking and unlocking a lock attached to a specific object (the lock is sometimes called a *monitor*). If one thread locks the lock, then another thread which tries to lock it will block. When the first thread unlocks the lock, the second thread unblocks, and carries on to lock the lock.

The `wait`/`notify` mechanism offers a way for a thread to temporarily give up a lock which it holds, with the reacquisition of the lock being controlled by some other thread which holds the lock in the meantime. Consider this code:

```
public synchronized void first() {
    System.out.println("first before");
    wait();
    System.out.println("first after");
}

public synchronized void second() {
    System.out.println("second before");
    notify();
    System.out.println("second after");
}
```

Say one thread, thread A, calls `first`, and then another, thread B, calls `second`. The sequence of events is:

1. A tries to acquire the lock
2. A succeeds in acquiring the lock
3. A goes to write "first before" to System.out
4. B tries to acquire the lock
5. B cannot acquire the lock, because A has it, so it blocks
6. A finishes writing, and calls `wait` - at this point A **releases the lock and instead starts waiting**
7. B now succeeds in acquiring the lock, and unblocks
8. B goes to write "second before" to System.out
9. B finishes writing, and calls `notify` - this has no effect on B, but it means that A **stops waiting and tries to reacquire the lock**
10. A cannot acquire the lock, because B has it, so it blocks
11. B goes to write "second after" to System.out
12. B finishes the method, and releases the lock
13. A now succeeds in acquiring the lock, and unblocks
14. A carries on and goes to write "first after" to System.out
15. A finishes the method, and releases the lock

This is a long-winded description, but it's really quite a simple process - the `wait`/`notify` calls sort of let the first thread lend the lock to another thread to use.

It's important to realise that there are two different kinds of blocking going on. Firstly, the way that threads block waiting to acquire a lock when they enter a `synchronized` block (or re-enter one on return from a `wait` call). Secondly, the way that threads block after calling `wait`, before being unblocked by a corresponding `notify`.

I have described `wait`/`notify` as being one thread lending another the lock. This is how i think about it, and i think it's a productive metaphor. To use a topically spooky metaphor, perhaps it's like a vampire who moves into a castle, then goes to sleep in his coffin. Once he's asleep, some innocent tourists come in and rent out the castle as a holiday home. At some point, the visitors explore the crypt and disturb the coffin, at which point the vampire wakes up and wants his castle back. Once the tourists have fled in terror, he can move back into the house.

The reason `wait` and `notify` have the names they do, rather than names like `lend` and `return`, is because they are usually used to build inter-thread communication mechanisms, where the emphasis is not on the initial lending of the lock by the first thread, but on the awakening of the waiter by the second thread.

Now, to finally turn to your second question, there are two things to think about.

The first one is the possibility of "spurious wake-ups" - see the tiny note deep in the nested bulleted lists in section [17.2.1. Wait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2.1) of the Java Language Specification:

> The thread may be removed from the wait set due to [...] An internal action by the implementation. Implementations are permitted, although not encouraged, to perform "spurious wake-ups", that is, to remove threads from wait sets and thus enable resumption without explicit instructions to do so.

That is, threads will normally only wake up when notified, but it is possible that they will randomly wake up when they have not been notified. Therefore, you do need to guard a `wait` with a loop involving a check on a condition variable, exactly as in your example. As the specification says:

> Notice that this provision necessitates the Java coding practice of using wait only within loops that terminate only when some logical condition that the thread is waiting for holds.

The second one is interruption. Interruption is not random; interruption only happens when some other thread has called `interrupt` on the thread that is waiting. When this happens, it will immediately stop blocking, and throw an `InterruptedException` out of the `wait` call. Contrary to what you have seen, it is *not* correct to catch this exception and wait again. The reason is very simple: if someone has called `interrupt` on your thread, it is precisely because they want you to `stop waiting`! It's impossible to say exactly what the thread should do instead, but the usual approach is to abort the current work, and return control to the caller. If the caller cannot continue after the current work is aborted, then it should also abort, and so on up the call stack until a level which can do something sensible is reached. Correct handling of interrupts is too big a subject to deal with here, but start by reading what the tutorial says about [Supporting Interruption](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html), and if possible, have a read of [Java Concurrency In Practice](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Java_Concurrency_in_Practice.html).

Comment: +1 Thanks! This explains it! Got a little confused on the waiting part. wait() is just another way for other threads to execute!

Answer (score 2):

> Will Object.wait be automatically called on the blocked thread?

Not really, it blocks on its monitor lock. You can refer to the documentation [for details on how this works](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html). Anyway details on how this is done internally are not really relevant to use `synchronized`, you can just use it knowing that only one thread will be allowed to execute the synchtonized block at any given time.

> Does this mean that we have to manually write a function like the
>   below in our class

No, synchronized does that for you. Synchronized blocks can only be accessed by one thread at a time, so the second thread will block until the first one has exited the synchronized block.

Comment: Thanks but when you say - synchronized does that for you, which synchronized are you referring to? I don't see any synchronized for wait method in Object class

Comment: This isn't a correct answer. `Object.wait()` is never implicitly called. When a thread wants to access synchronized block, and another thread has the monitor, then it will enter a queue for the monitor, that is not the same as when `wait()` is called, which means the Thread will wait until `notify()` or `notifyAll()` is called.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You're correct, it doesn't call `Object.wait`. I actually never cared on how JVM does this. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @UserInteractive Then sorry I don't understand the second question. You mean how to use `wait` instead of `synchronized` block?

Comment: @m0skit0 Now I see that Object.wait is not implicitly called! So, does this mean that we have to call it in our code if we want the threads to be inactive till it is notified?

Comment: If you're using `synchronized`, it is enough, you don't need to call `wait` or anything else. `synchronized` takes care of all that stuff (blocking/unblocking threads) for you.

Comment: Thanks! Just curious to know..doesn't this call Object.wait implicitly? 'cause you mentioned saying synchronized takes care of everything

Comment: No, as noted by @MarkRotteveel in his comment. It uses monitor queues if you check the link I've added ;) `Object.wait` is not the only way to block a thread.